# Work done in a weird scenario

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work

[image]

This was a question asked in JEE Mains 2020, an engineering exam in India. It's common knowledge for anyone writing the exam that work done is the area under the PV graph. I gave this question to a few friends, and according to few of them, the answer is 48. According to me and few others it should be 68, since there is area under this graph too, which is hidden by the question maker showing that the graph begins from (2,2). To explain the answer 48, some of my friends said you just shift the origin to (2,2), and I believe I have a much better grasp of mathematics, and claimed that that operation is wrong, you are changing the function being plotted in such a scenario. But, I can't seem to be able to convince them to not consider (2,2) as the origin of the graph, as they are changing the values of real life functions.

I also believe, they seem to have difficulty understanding the concept of what origin means. According to them, it refers to the point where both the axes meet. According to me, origin is just the point where both functions are 0. Axes tell you nothing extraordinary, they just help you locate the value a point represents, and map a certain direction to increase or decrease of a function. And axes don't need to be marked from the origin, according to my understanding, they should just help us locate the value of the particular function they correspond to, for a certain point. So at the intersection of the two *weird* axes stated in the question, the pressure is 2 and volume is 2. Shifting the origin changes the function we plot to `Pressure - 2` and `Volume - 2` which have no significance with the real life functions.

Could anyone please share a convincing solution for as to why it's 68 (considering the complete view of the graph) or disprove me as to why the answer should be 48 (only the area under graph given)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you not tried drawing the graph with $(0,0)$ as where the axes intersect? Also, why have arguments over horribly-made "trick" questions? This is obviously intended to trick someone rather than test their actual physics knowledge and understanding.

Comment: @BioPhysicist that's how I had solved it, by redrawing the graph from (0,0).

Comment: Right. And C ends at the point (12,2). It asks about the work done in the region _bounded by ABC-A.

Comment: @josephh No... Just along the path from A to B to C. It's an expansion, not a cycle

Comment: What would be the work done in the region bounded by ABC-A? That's the answer.

Comment: @josephh I'm not sure what is going on here.  It literally says path ABC. Not cycle ABCA. Where are you getting this from?

Comment: @josephh I'm still not sure where you are getting this from... The question literally says path ABC. Start at A. Go to B. Go to C. That's all. That is path ABC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an integral "the area under a graph" is a very convenient shorthand, but it is not a literally accurate description of what an integral is. It sounds like your friends have learned this shorthand without actually learning what an integral is.

A more pedantically accurate but still informal way to describe the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ might be something like "The signed area of the region bounded by the graph of $f$, the horizontal line through $(0,0)$, and the vertical lines through $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$." Here "the graph of $f$" means the set of points $(x,f(x))$, and "signed area" is positive for subregions where $f(x)$ is positive and negative when $f(x)$ is negative. This description has its flaws, but it at least gets around your friends' misunderstanding.

However, I think that rather than trying to convince your friends that this is what we mean when we talk about the "area under the graph," you could try to appeal to the uniqueness of the integral. When it's defined, $\int_a^b f$ should always be the same number regardless of who is calculating it; it depends on what the function $f$ is and not any pictures we may choose to draw of $f$. As long as they accept that calculating the area when the horizontal axis passes through the origin is *a* way to get an integral, they should be able to see that it's the *only* way.

If your friends don't believe or can't be convinced that an integral is a unique number, you may want to consider finding new study partners.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It explains quite clearly the fault in their interpretation. Much appreciated!